# Unable to take a 20 byte hex input from Qlinedit and store into Qstring

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to take 20 byte hex input from `QlinEdit` and I want to validate `QlinEdit` for only 20 bytes and also store it into `QString` .

I have Done for trial purpose :

```
ui->SetValue->setMaxLength(4);
ui->SetValue->setInputMask("Hh hh hh hh");
```

But It is giving me 11 bytes instead of 4 bytes.

and the hex values are not coming in pair in `QString`. What Should I do?

I have tried everything but I'm not able to do that.

I have used:

```
ui->SetValue->setInputMask("Hh hh hh hh");

    else if (ui->checkBox_HEX->isChecked())
    {
        ui->SetValue->setEnabled(true);

        obj = ui->SetValueUniqueId->text();

        QByteArray bytes = obj.toLatin1();

        int length = myHexArray.size(); //Number of bytes

        printf("Number Of bytes = %d", length);


        memcpy(buffer, obj.toStdString().c_str(), obj.size());
```

Comment: Unable to take 20 byte hex input from Qlinedit and store into Qstring

Comment: QLineEdit still gives you text. Use QByteArray::fromHex.

Comment: But I'm using Qt for the first time , And I don't know how to use  QByteArray::fromHex. can you please give an example for it, It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: If you solve your problem based on my comment, feel free to write your own answer showing what you did.

Comment: I want to take take 20 byte hex input from QLineEdit and store it Into 20 byte char array

Comment: Check th docs...

Comment: What are the desired input outpu pairs ? Ie what is the user entering on the screen and what is the expected char array you have in return?

Comment: Regarding your input mask: It requires 8 hex digits -> 4 bytes. So, for 20 bytes it's just too short. Btw. this is contradictory to your other setting `ui->SetValue->setMaxLength(4);`. A string of 4 characters can definitely not store 20 hex digits... ;-)

Comment: Hi UmNyobe                                                                                                            user will take input from UI through  QlinEdit  =  It should be 20 bye hex value for e.g    ab ac ad ae af dc da de df .......upto 20 byte.                 char array should fill like :-  char[0] =" ab "   ,  char[1] = "ac"  ....upto 20 bytes

Comment: How to take 20 byte hex input from QlinEdit  and then first store it into Qstring and from Qstring copy it into char array like :- char[0] = "ab",char[1] = "ad"....upto 20 byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I never used [`QLineEdit::setInputMask()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) before, I made an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) – to provide an answer as well as for my own entertainment.

There are two essential parts in this sample:

```
qTxtIn.setInputMask(
  QString::fromLatin1(
    "HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH"));
```

sets the input mask of `QLineEdit` to accept 20 × 2 characters for which "Hexadecimal character required. A-F, a-f, 0-9." (Remember, one byte → two hex digits.)

(Note that `h` in opposition permits hex digits but does not require.)

The other part is in the lambda which I used as signal handler to convert the hex digit input into the corresponding byte values:

```
QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromHex(text.toLatin1());
```

Thereby, `text` is a `QString` with the current text of the `QLineEdit qTxtIn` (the signal sender). (Alternatively, I could have used `qTxtIn.text()`.) `QString` uses internally some kind of Unicode encoding (on Windows probably UTF-16).

The `QByteArray::fromHex()` can interprete text input decoding hex-digits to byte values. The only issue – it expects a `QByteArray` as input.

Therefore, the `QString` is converted to `QByteArray` (before applied to `QByteArray::fromHex()`) using the method `QString::toLatin1()`. Consider, that [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) provides *much* less characters than [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). However, in the case of hex-digits this really is no problem as the digits 0 ... 9 as well as the letters a ... f (and A ... F) are available in Latin1 also.

The rest is what I considered entertainment – in my case converting the bytes to a C string to make them printable again.

The complete sample code `testQLineEdit-Hex.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // build appl.
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // build GUI
  QWidget qMainWin;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QLabel qLblIn(QString::fromUtf8("Input (20 hex bytes):"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblIn, 0, 0);
  QLineEdit qTxtIn;
  qTxtIn.setInputMask(
    QString::fromLatin1(
      "HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTxtIn, 0, 1);
  QLabel qLblOut(QString::fromUtf8("Output (C string):"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblOut, 1, 0);
  QLineEdit qTxtOut;
  qTxtOut.setReadOnly(true);
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTxtOut, 1, 1);
  qMainWin.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qMainWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTxtIn, &QLineEdit::textEdited,
    [&qTxtOut](const QString &text) {
      // get bytes from input
      QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromHex(text.toLatin1());
      // encode bytes as C String
      QString textOut;
      for (const char c : bytes) {
        switch (c) {
          case '\"': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\\""); break;
          case '\a': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\a"); break;
          case '\b': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\b"); break;
          case '\f': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\f"); break;
          case '\n': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\n"); break;
          case '\r': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\r"); break;
          case '\t': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\t"); break;
          case '\v': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\v"); break;
          case '\\': textOut += QString::fromLatin1("\\\\"); break;
          default:
            if (c >= ' ' && c < '\x7f') textOut += c;
            else textOut += QString("\\%1").arg((int)(uchar)c, 3, 8, QChar('0'));
        }
      }
      qTxtOut.setText(textOut);
    });
  // exec. application
  return app.exec();
}
```

I compiled and tested in VS2013 with Qt 5.9.2 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: Snapshot of test-QLineEdit-Hex]

As you can see, I praticed my memory about ASCII values...

Comment: Thank you Scheff , My 80% problems are  resolved by referring above code, but while copying Qstring into char buffer it is taking values like e.g char[1] = " 4 ", char[1] = " 8 ", char[2] = " 6 ".....it becomes 40 bytes instead of 20 bytes, Means it spiting the input hex into separate bytes , But i want copy pair of hex as one byte into char buffer for e.g char[1] = "48", char[1] = "65", char[2] = "6c"...etc

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 Not sure whether I got you: When converting between `QString` and a char buffer, use conversion functions carefully. A `QString` uses internally some kind of Unicode encoding (on Windows probably UTF-16). Hence, there are a lot of characters possible which cannot be converted to plain ASCII. Note all of the `QString::from...()` methods I put into my code... (even although they often might not be really necessary).

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 Reading twice your comment, I'm still puzzled. In my sample, I made input `48` and it converted to `H` (which is exactly the ASCII character `0x48`). So, what?

Comment: but in my case the hex values are splitting into two different values.  To copy Qstring into char I'm using :-    memcpy(buffer, String.toStdString().c_str(), String.size()); .... Is there any problem with memcopy?

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 It depends: Using `memcpy()` as in your sample, copys the hex digits _as text_ to your buffer. If you want this fine. If not, just do it as I emphasized in my answer: use `QByteArray::fromHex()` instead. Please, have a look at Qt doc.: [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details). It provides a lot of convenience. Among a lot of other options, you can at least `memcpy(buffer, byteArray.data(), 20);` assuming `char buffer[20];` and `QByteArray byteArray;` and `byteArray.size() >= 20`.

Comment: @ Scheff  I have one more query , I want to copy 20 byte from QlinEdit hex value into 20 byte char array. I tried many ways to do it, But i didin't get anything.

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 To understand this, you should (urgently) learn about two things: 1. how to use the Qt doc. (it's one of the best docs I know for any API) 2. character encodings. In your special case, probably the following will work: [`QLineEdit::text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) returns `QString` -> [`QString::toLatin1()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) and [`QString::toLocal8Bit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit) return `QByteArray`. Which one of the latter is the right for your purpose depends on expected encoding.

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 If you expect simple ASCII (values from 1 ... 127) you can use `QString::toLatin1()`.

Comment: User enter 40 values in QlinEdit and Qstring also takes as it is 40 values ,But i want to coy the 40 values in char array[20], for e.g user enters 48 65 6c 6c6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 20 33 ad be 66 00 01 02 in QlinEdit and I also want to copy as it is in char array[20] like array[0]= "48", array[1]= "65"...etc ...

Comment: You _cannot_ store `"48"` in a `char`. You _can_ store `48` in a `char` as well as `0x48`. Did you get the difference? The first is a string of two `char`s plus (in certain cases) a 0-terminator. The second and third are `int` values in the range a `char` can store. To _convert_ the string `"48"` to a `char` with value `0x48` - that's just what `QByteArray::fromHex()` does. That's why I emphasized it in my answer.

Comment: @Bhagyesh_99 I edited my answer and added some more details about how the hex-input gets converted to bytes. (Funny enough: "Hexe" is in German the word for witch. I didn't realize to do such "Hexenwerk" i.e. witchcraft.)